# passing parameter through axios post call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have this (my whole page):

```
 import { render } from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "../styles/TourPage.css";

class TourPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myData: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("/getResults")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          myData: res.data
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle the errors here
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false
        });
      });
  }

  deleteById = (id) => {

    console.log(id)
    axios
      .post(`/deleteDoc`, id )
      .then(() => {
        console.log(id, " worked")
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle the errors here
        console.log(error);

  })
}
  render() {
    // You can handle the loader part here with isLoading flag. In this case No data found will be shown initially and then the actual data
    let { myData, isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
      <table id="customers">
        <tr>
          <th>siteLocation</th>
          <th>Services</th>
          <th>cnum</th>
        </tr>
        {myData.length > 0
          ? myData.map(({ location, Services, cnum, _id }, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{location}</td>
                <td>{Services}</td>
                <td>{cnum}</td>
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.deleteById(_id)}
                  disabled={isLoading}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
              </tr>
            ))
          : "No Data Found"}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default TourPage;
```

what it does is basically load the results from the database, and then If I want to delete them, I click the button, and it delete them. pretty straight forward stuff. My issue is, when I click the delete button, and it makes the axios post request, it doesn't actually pass the `id` to the backend. in my backend, I have this:

```
 app.post('/deleteDoc', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.id)
})
```

however, when I run it, it goes back there, but shows `undefined` in my console.

any ideas why this may happen?

Comment: do you have a bodyparser on your "backend"

Comment: yes, I do. and I know it works because on my other function it is passing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `axios.post("/end", {id: id})`. Body is an object where you are accessing id key.

Answer (score 1):

When you call API using AXIO, HTTP POST method always you need to assign JSON object as body. So your code need to change as below.

```js
  axios
      .post(`/deleteDoc`, {id} )
      .then(() => {
        console.log(id, " worked")
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle the errors here
        console.log(error);

  })
```

*

> Note: Normally REST methods are self-explanatory, Since this is a
> delete scenario, better to use HTTP DELETE method with ID in URL path
> param.

- 